# Multiple of 5 checking

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

How is this code working for multiple of 5

```
bool isMultipleof5(int n)
{
    /* If n is a multiple of 5 then we make sure that last
       digit of n is 0 */
    if ( (n&1) == 1 )
        n <<= 1;

    float x = n;
    x = ( (int)(x*0.1) )*10;

    /* If last digit of n is 0 then n will be equal to (int)x */
    if ( (int)x == n )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What about `if( (n % 5)==0) return true; return false;`?

Comment: Or `return (n%5) == 0;`

Comment: Why would last digit be `0`? `5` is a multiple of `5` and it is `101` in binary. `105` is also a multiple of `5` and it is `1101001` in binary.

Comment: What about `return (n % 5) == 0`?

Comment: @sharptooth, shouldn't `return (n % 5) == 0;` be enough?

Comment: @zzzzBov: A bit less convenient when stepping over in the debugger. Of course I mean that my `if` and an extra `return` are on different lines.

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of homework and he's not able to use modulus operator.

Comment: This code definitely does not work as written, because there's no such floating point number as 0.1.

Comment: @R. Unless you've got a machine that uses decimal floating point. They're pretty rare though.

Comment: What about using **macro** instead of function: `#define isMultipleOf5(x) (x % 5 == 0)` ?

Comment: @R.. At least g++ on x86 is able to make the code work for values less than `16777235` even with the `0.1` literal.

Comment: @sharptooth, why would you need to use a debugger on `(n % 5) == 0`?

Comment: @MarkB: I suppose `0.1` (the `double`) is slightly larger than 0.1 (the numeric value), so it probably won't break, but it could easily fail if the floating point precision were a bit different and the closest value to 0.1 was slightly smaller than 0.1. Writing `0.1` in C is almost always a bug, but the expression of the bug may be rare, subtle, and/or platform-specific.

Comment: @zzzzBov: You never know where the program breaks apart .

Comment: @sharptooth, I suppose with a language such as `C++` and operator overloading, simple assumptions such as `a % b` returning a particular value could be incorrect...

Comment: @zzzzBov: Assumptions are great unless you've spent several hours debugging that code already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the code works with some examples.

```
if ( (n&1) == 1 ) //Checks if the number is odd
    n <<= 1; //Multiplies the number by 2 if odd

x = ( (int)(x * 0.1) //Divides the number 10 then truncates any decimal places
    * 10 ) //Multiplies it back by 10

if ( (int)x == n ) //If the floating point value equals the (semi) original value its divisible by 5
        return true;

return false; //Other wise false
```

Example:

```
15 & 1 == 1 //15 is odd
15 <<= 1; //n is now 30

30 / 10 = 3;
3 * 10 = 30; //x is now 30

30 == 30 //15 is a multiple of 5
```

---

```
17 & 1 == 1 //17 is odd
17 <<= 1; //n is now 34

34 / 10 = 3.4;
((int)3.4 = 3) * 10 = 30; //x is now 30

30 != 34 //17 is not a multiple of 5.
```

As others said though just simply use the mod operator `%`.

Answer (score 8):

It first makes `n` divisable by 2.

Next, it checks if it is divisable by 10 by multiplying with `0.1` and again with `10`. The idea that if it is divisable by `10`, you will get back to the original, and only then.

So, if the modifies `n` is divisable by 10 - it is certainly divisable by 5 as well, and since modified `n` is always divisable by 2, if it is divisable by 5 it will be divisable by 10, and the algorithm works.

**NOTE**: This is very unsuggested and especially **might break** with large values due to floating point precision issues. using the `%` operator should be prefered: `return (n % 5) == 0`

Comment: With an IEEE754 `float` it breaks for a wide variety of numbers greater than or equal to `16777225` (where the float doesn't have enough bits for the integral part basically).

Comment: @amit, only person to answer the question and not suggest another way. +1 from me.

Comment: It should also be noted that the floating point conversion is unnecessary. Dividing by 10 as an integer would truncate the value. Of course, if they're avoiding the modulus, they may be trying to avoid all integer division.  Or maybe the compiler was optimizing away the operation if left as (n/10)*10

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
bool isMultipleof5(int n)
{
   return (n%5) == 0;
}
```

Comment: `return` is not a function, no need for the outer parenthesis.

Comment: Only the (n%5) part is inside parantheses.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works:

1. Double the number. Now anything ending in 5 will be divisible 10 (and also divisible by 5). `n <<= 1;` (the check for oddness is unnecessary `(n&1) == 1`)
2. Divide it by 10, and cast away the fractional part. `(int)(x*0.1)`
3. Multiply it by 10, so now we have the same number as in step 1 only if the number in step 1 was already divisible by 10.

The use of floating point to divide by 10 makes this algorithm dangerous and probably incorrect for large values.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way would be

```
bool isMultipleof5(int n)
{
    return 0 == ( n % 5 ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define IS_MULTIPLE_OF_5(n) (((n)%5) ? 0 : 1)
```

Comment: You don't need the ternary operator to do this.

Comment: Correct. You don't need the preprocessor either. Or a (boolean) function. In cases where the test is used is a condition (== almost all cases), the result will be optimised away anyway (given function inlining)

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree that (n % 5) == 0 would be an ideal solution, but that wasn't really the question.

This code works because it first checks if the input is odd. If it is, it multiplies by two. Since all odd multiples of 5 end with a 5, multiplying by 2 gives a number that ends with 0.

Then it checks if the last digit is 0.  This can only happen if it started as a 0 (i.e. was even, we didn't change it) or if it was odd and ended in a 5 (we multiplied by 2). So, if it ends in 0 then the input must have been divisible by 5.

I'd add that this is also an awkward way to check the value of the last digit. I'd suggest n % 10 == 0 instead, but like others mentioned... you could have just used n % 5 == 0 in the first place ;).